# in php code the col-md-4 divs appear underneath each other not side by side

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

the following php code is performing just as I expect, but the "col-md-4" divs are appearing underneath each other, rather than showing three in a row.

Can anybody help me with what I have done wrong?

```
<?php

$previousCat = null; // starts the category at NULL

while(!$DETAILS->atEnd()) {

// Check if GENUS if different. If yes then display GENUS and start row to contain all varieties
if($DETAILS->getColumnVal("GENUS") != $previousCat) {

    echo '<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 g-my-10 g-bg-pale"><h2>'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("GENUS").'</h2></div>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">';
 }

// now we output whatever is needed at the start of a new group - in this case,
// user name and date, since we want those only once
echo '
 <div class="col-md-4" data-animate-inview="20" style="min-height: 345px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px">
 <p><img src="17_photos/'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("IMAGE").'" title="'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("VARIETY").'" class="img-fluid" /></p>
 <p><strong>'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("VARIETY").'</strong>
 <br />'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("DESCRIPTION").'
 <br />'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("TYPE").'</p>
 </div>
';

// if GENUS is different end the row that contains the varieties
if($DETAILS->getColumnVal("GENUS") != $previousCat) {

    echo '</div>';
} 


// save the GENUS for comparison with next GENUS
$previousCat = $DETAILS->getColumnVal("GENUS"); 

$DETAILS->moveNext();
}
$DETAILS->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record


?>
```

Output code is as follows - it looks like an extra div is being placed after the first col-md-4

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 g-my-10 g-bg-pale"><h2>Asian Greens</h2></div>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4" data-animate-inview="20" style="min-height: 345px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px">
 <p><img src="17_photos/02897.07.Tatsoi.cat.jpg" title="Tatsoi" class="img-fluid" /></p>
 <p><strong>Tatsoi</strong>
 <br />dark spicy asian green
 <br /></p>
 </div>
 </div><div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 g-my-10 g-bg-pale"><h2>Beets</h2></div>  
    </div>
    <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4" data-animate-inview="20" style="min-height: 345px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px">
 <p><img src="17_photos/nopic.jpg" title="Baby Beats" class="img-fluid" />
 </p>
 <p><strong>Baby Beats</strong>
 <br />
 <br /></p>
 </div>
</div>
 <div class="col-md-4" data-animate-inview="20" style="min-height: 345px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px">
 <p><img src="17_photos/nopic.jpg" title="Blankoma" class="img-fluid" /></p>
 <p><strong>Blankoma</strong>
 <br />white, round
 <br /></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: You should post a sample of the output HTML when viewing your page source. After that, this becomes mostly a CSS/HTML question and not PHP.

Comment: are these in a `container` or `container-fluid` (of horizontal form?)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I've posted the html output. It seems to place an extra div on the first instance of each col-md-4 when the GENUS changes. I can;t see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Hi Apokryfos, yes they are in a container  that is outside of the php code, but surrounding it properly I believe.

Comment: @Bill Teale, I think what apokryfos is asking is: which class does the container use? Where it can be either container or container-fluid. (i.e., <div id='mycontainer' class='container'></div> or <div id='mycontainer' class='container-fluid'></div>)

Comment: I think you are, not only closing, but adding an additional row, before you when you should close the row. If you want two (2) cols to show up side by side, you need to treat them similar to table tr's and td's. If you create a row and inside of it, crate two cols. When the display or viewport is of a reasonable size (which can be managed via media-queries) it can be displayed as two cols, side-by-side. Or, if it's not large enough, it can be displayed one on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you are creating a new row with this condition:

```
if($DETAILS->getColumnVal("GENUS") != $previousCat)
```

You are then using that same condition to end your row. The first iteration of the loop creating the row will therefore always end the row after the first col-md-4 div because you are only changing the value of $previousCat afterwards. However, changing the value of $previousCat before will also likely give you problems with closing your row div as intended.

For a less elegant solution, a boolean variable that you check for in that last conditional statement and set in your first conditional would work. This would let you determine if a new row has been *freshly* created in that iteration and therefore should not be ended in that same iteration. This is usually indicative that there are some changes to logic to be made.

Comment: Thank you I shall let you know how it goes. Can you suggest a tutorial for the jQuery solution?

Comment: I'm actually going to edit out the jQuery portion of my original answer, as I was inadvertently projecting my own design needs and making too many assumptions about yours.

Javascript and subsequently jQuery are something you would look at using for manipulating these elements independent of page rendering like for event handling, polling, etc. The way you are handling initial HTML generation with PHP is the correct way to do it, and you don't need jQuery for what you have shown so far, and in fact, you and I were both able to come up with solutions making changes to the logic.

Comment: I really appreciate your help bboll, your answer really helped me find my way.  Not sure who or why I got -3 on this question, I worded it as clearly as I knew how, and didn't find anything similar anywhere, but the main thing is you and the other responders helped me find the answer - thank you!

Comment: I think the main issue that some may have had with your question is that it is a question with a solution likely specific to you. It is hard to categorize it in such a way that someone with a similar problem could identify and find it. This site tends to avoid questions like that and most answers try to extrapolate general solutions and best practices from them, which I was trying to do by suggesting jQuery (too eagerly). Also, I think your initial assumption that your PHP code was performing as you expected had viewers thinking it was mislabeled. Glad you were able to find a solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was take the class "row" out of the php, and working with col-md-12 and col-md-4 in the php coding, using an if else statement as follows...

```
<section class="container-fluid no-gutters">
<div class="row" id="list">

<?php

$previousCat = null; // starts the category at NULL

while(!$DETAILS->atEnd()) {

  // Check if GENUS if different. If yes then display GENUS and start row to contain all varieties

  if($DETAILS->getColumnVal("GENUS") != $previousCat) {

    echo '<div class="col-md-12" style="clear:both">

    <div class="w-50 g-my-10 g-bg-pale"><h2>'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("GENUS").'</h2></div>  
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="min-height: 345px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px">
 <p><img src="17_photos/'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("IMAGE").'" title="'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("VARIETY").'" class="img-fluid " style="max-width:80%" /></p>
 <p><strong>'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("VARIETY").'</strong>
 <br />'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("DESCRIPTION").'
 <br />'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("TYPE").'</p>
 </div>
';
}
// if GENUS is not different
else {


echo '
 <div class="col-md-4" style="min-height: 345px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px">
 <p><img src="17_photos/'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("IMAGE").'" title="'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("VARIETY").'" class="img-fluid " style="max-width:80%" /></p>
 <p><strong>'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("VARIETY").'</strong>
 <br />'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("DESCRIPTION").'
 <br />'.$DETAILS->getColumnVal("TYPE").'</p>
 </div>
';
    }


  // save the GENUS for comparison with next GENUS
  $previousCat = $DETAILS->getColumnVal("GENUS"); 

  $DETAILS->moveNext();
}
$DETAILS->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record


?>
 </div>
</section>
```